# ffmpeg audio voices only on right side

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-converter

I am converting some high quality movies to lower quality with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output_video.mp4
```

The output result causes that (in some cases) audio of voices are only reproduced on the right side of the earphones. I have to execute these two commands to have the proper audio:

```
ffmpeg -i output_video.mp4 -map 0:a:0 -async 1 audio.mp3
ffmpeg -i output_video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output_video_with_audio.mp4
```

I have tried adding mapping parameters (-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -async 1) to the first command, but I have the same audio problem result.

What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Do you need to reencode audio? If not, try the first command with `-c:a copy` option t

Comment: thank you so much @kesh, you saved me many hours of work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (from kesh comment in OP): add "-c:a copy". Final command would be:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -c:a copy output_video.mp4
```